# A single English word for "not chaos"

Tags: word-choice, language

Pretty much what it says in the title. A single English word, that can preferably be used as a noun.

Are there any antonyms that use chaos as a root word?

Comment: Hi, welcome to writers! Questions about vocabulary belong to [English SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/). Read [this page](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/875/writers-se-on-topic-summary) for a summary of what's on-opic here, and [this one](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2474/faq-on-topic-off-topic-list-revisal) for what's on topic for English SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common antonym to "chaos" is "order". See http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chaos

If you need an antonym that contains "chaos" as a root, then you have to create one, as it does not exist. Possibilities include "non-chaos" and "dischaos". I wouldn't use "inchaos", as that might lead to confusion with "inchoate", which means something else entirely. The neologism "dischaos" [has been used](http://www.ralph-abraham.org/articles/MS%2376.Dischaos/) by mathematician Ralph Abraham as the opposite of "chaos", but it seems less self-explanatory than "non-chaos" to me and I would only use it when addressing a highly educated audience.